# How to make shortcuts on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: shortcuts, 17.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 but all my desktop shortcuts are gone.

There is no longer a **Create Shortcut** option when I right-click either.

How do I add these now?

Answer (score 11):

Launch *Files* and open its *Preferences*:

[image]

Go to the *Behaviour* (tab) and check "*Show action to create symbolic links*" under *Link Creation*.

[image]

Right click to create a link to a file or folder should work now.

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67472/discussion-between-pomsky-and-eliminator).

Comment: This would be great but my "Files" does not have that Menu with Nautilus. Can you be more specific with "Open Files"?

Comment: Got it..."File Management" But still doesn't have "Link Creation" Option.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff I think I don't understand completely. Are you not able get to the "Preferences"? You'll have to open "Files" (Nautilus) and click on the application name (i.e. "Files") on the top bar next to "Activities". A drop-down menu should appear which has the "Preferences" option.

Comment: Look at this....https://imgur.com/3WkRxJd

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if the existing answer actually answers the  question.  My understanding is that the user wants to create an icon on the Desktop that will open a file or application stored somewhere on the computer.  This involves creating a `.desktop` file in the `~/Desktop` folder.

The easiest way I have found to do this is create a new text file in the `~/Desktop` folder and then add content as follows (assuming the link is to an application):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[es_ES]=/path/to/the/application/icon
Name[es_ES]=theApplicationName
Exec=/path/to/the/application/executable
GenericName[es_ES.UTF-8]=Arbitrary text describing the application
```

Note that the language specifications might be different (e.g. `en_UK`).

Give the file exec permissions.

The link should appear on the desktop.  If it is an application, when you double-click on it for the first time you will be asked for permission to run it.  Click on the appropriate button.  The desktop icon will now change to show the application icon and to use the application name as the icon's legend.

If I've misunderstood the previous answer or, indeed, the question and this answer is redundant, my apologies.

Comment: You can leave the language information out if you only create one set of information anyways.

Comment: Wow, is this really *the* way to create an application shortcut in Gnome Shell? :( A pretty convoluted solution to a very common usage...