# How to activate the option of "make link" with right click?

Tags: nautilus, shortcuts, settings, symbolic-link, system-settings

I want to create a shortcut of a folder on my desktop and I want to do it with the option of "make link" which is not there when I right-click on the folder. I don't want to use billion of commands on the terminal to do it. In another threat someone said that "make link" option is not visible by default and I have to set it in some options. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make shortcuts on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967484/how-to-make-shortcuts-on-ubuntu-17-10) This answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/967485/480481